# System.Web.Mvc.dll Execution Order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to figure out the rough flow of the code within the System.Web.Mvc.dll and the related DLLs (Razor, WebPages).

I have a controller in an MVC web application. This controller has an endpoint which returns a ViewResult. Where does this ViewResult go next? Specifically, how does the View information propagate down to the Razor Engine and get rendered? What part of the code makes that call?

I've tried to debug against the source but am having a hard time getting that going so I was hoping for an overview if someone is familiar with that code. An overview of the flow would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doubtful as it may be that this will actually help someone, I hacked together a rough sketch of the flow without the debugger.

This is obviously not 100% exact but with this the general idea should be clear:
ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult => ViewResult.FindView 
=> ViewEngineCollection.FindView => VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView => 
if not found => abstract CreateView => RazorViewEngine.CreateView => View.Render (BuildManagedCompiledView.Render: actually compiles and creates the page) =>  RazorView.RenderView (actually calls the ExecutePageHierarchy command)